# react nested children route is not working

Tags: reactjs

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Content from "../../Public/pages/Content/Content";
import { Home } from "@mui/icons-material";
const Route = createBrowserRouter([
    

    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home></Home>, // working 
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Content /> children is not working
            }
        ]
    },

])

export default Route;
```

Content Should show on the page but it's not working and it's not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the child with the same `path`, that's not possible. How would React-Router know which route to render ;)

---

You'll need to add an unique `path` to the child, for example let's make the url `/content`:

```
const Route = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home></Home>,
        children: [
            {
                path: "content",
                element: <Content />
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

---

For more information and examples, please check the [`createBrowserRouter()` documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router).

Comment: Why not possible? They are not siblings, they are nested routes. The element in parent is used as a container, so the children can have the same path as the parent. Otherwise the path ```/``` will be useless if non of the children can use it

Answer (score 0):

The element in parent is used as a container and it does not know where to render its children. You must use `Outlet` inside the parent

Here is the documentation https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

```
import { createBrowserRouter, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Content from "../../Public/pages/Content/Content";
const Route = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <div>this is parent and this outlet is the child <Outlet /></div>
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Content />
            }
        ]
    },

])

export default Route;
```

The children is rendered where the parent Outlet is located